# is it possible to make contractions set a metric space?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two metric spaces with distances respectively $d_X$, $d_Y$. Is it possible to make contractions set a metric space?

Contracts set is the set of function from $X$ to $Y$ such that $d_X(x, y) \leq d_Y(f (x), f (y))$. I thought about using induced metric but I can't understand how to go on.
Have you any hint?

Comment: I guess you want to say $d_Y(f(x),f(y)) \le d_X(x,y)$. Hence the contractions are continuous functions.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can consider the following distance $\delta$ on your set :

$$\forall f,g, \quad \delta(f,g)=\min \lbrace \sup_{x \in X}d_Y(f(x),g(x)), 1 \rbrace$$

Comment: And I can consider this metric such as induced metric?

Comment: Well, contractions are continuous functions so you can consider this metric as the induced metric from the one on the set of continuous functions.

Comment: why did you definit distance δ  like that?

Comment: The supremum distance is the classical distance on sets of functions, but without hypothesis, it is not well-defined because the sup can be infinite. To avoid this problem, taking the min with 1 makes your distance finite and well-defined.

Comment: okay, now I understand. thank you